# Can a bipolar capacitor in an AC circuit store even a tiny amount of energy?

Tags: capacitor, ac

I've been reading (some Q&As on here and other bits on the web) about the behaviour of bipolar capacitors in AC circuits.

I understand that a polarised capacitor cannot work and will likely explode in an AC circuit due to the voltage going negative for half of the AC cycle. Only a bipolar cap can  be used with AC.

So let's say we have a simple AC circuit consisting of a 230V AC power source (pure sine wave) with a bipolar capacitor and a resistive load connected in parallel.  I understand that, in this scenario, if source power is removed, the cap cannot be relied upon (at least in practise) to work like a battery as it would in a DC circuit and if it were polarised.  It can "store" the AC voltage value at the particular instant that source power is removed, the value at the particular point of the the AC sinusoidal wave.

But what I can't seem to find the answer to yet, maybe because I just don't get something fundamental: if source power is removed, and the wave is at some point in the positive half of the cycle at that instant, can there be any energy left in the cap at all, even a tiny amount, which is then released into the circuit *after* source power disconnection? Assuming 50Hz with each cycle taking 20ms, if the wave happened to be at +230V, does that mean there could be 10ms of "run time" left in the circuit after source power is removed?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Thanks. So, without extra components it's possible but will happen only sometimes/unreliably? Does that just depend on where in the cycle the voltage is? I've read about so called tank circuits by adding an inductor but seems at 230V would require a cap of at least several Farads.

Comment: If you disconnect at a zero crossing, the capacitor will store 0 power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A capacitor does not magically work differently in AC. It tries to maintain a steady voltage, causing a current flow to do so. This has some interesting *effects* when the source is AC (such as leading current, and reactive power) but the mechanism is not different.

So yes, if the AC source is disconnected, the capacitor will try to maintain the voltage it has. That's just what a capacitor does. It does that all the time, not just when disconnected from an AC source. If the voltage happens to be +230V then it will try to maintain +230V. Whether this is useful for your circuit is a different matter.

---

A capacitor in parallel with an AC source is most likely not a useful way to store power because, as you already noticed, the voltage could be 0V when the AC source is disconnected. If you need energy storage then you should look at other solutions. If your circuit converts AC to DC then it is much more sensible to use a capacitor in the DC part of the circuit. If your circuit involves rotating parts it might be more useful to use a flywheel.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135813/discussion-on-answer-by-user253751-can-a-bipolar-capacitor-in-an-ac-circuit-stor).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there can be some energy stored. If the supply is disconnected at the peak supply voltage, this could be as much as 1.41 times the RMS supply voltage. That's about 325V for a 230V AC supply.

For devices that can be unplugged, this can be a safety hazard for users, who aren't expecting a high DC voltage across the pins of the plug they have just pulled out. The usual solution is an appropriate resistor in parallel with the capacitor. It's typically a few hundred kilohms. The resistor discharges the capacitor before the users have a chance to touch the plug pins.

Comment: So, **NEVER** touch the pins of the plug you just pull out as you don't know the resistor is still in good condition. Just take a metal tool as a "short". Don't touch the tool with your hands while doing this discharge "action".